# How do I connect a hardware interrupt to Qt Emit?

Tags: linux, qt4, embedded

I'm building and embedded app and I rather use a hardware interrupt listener then chew up cpu cycles by polling every 10th of a second.

This obviously can be done since there are listener for hardware interrupts like the keyboard, mouse and networking. What I would ultimately like to do is have a hardware interrupt trigger a Qt emit signal.

Thanks in advance.

Example:
Hardware interrupt -> readPort() -> emit(value)
**UPDATE**
I think something like this would work but I like to hear from someone that has experience with this.

```
mSN = new QSocketNotifier; // defined in .h
QFile file("/dev/testDriver");
if(file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
  QSocketNotifier mSN(file.handle(), , QSocketNotifier::Read);
  mSN.setEnabled(true);
  connect(mSN, SIGNAL(activated(int)), &this, SLOT(readyRead()));
}
```

Comment: hardware interrupts are handled only by the kernel. You might make a device driver which sends them as output. Qt is application level, and knows only about file descriptors and Unix signals.

Comment: Yes - you need a driver, as suggested by @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: I understand the concept of a hardware drive that runs in the kernel space with read,write, ioctrl etc. The question is how to avoid polling, not kernel vs user space.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing anything else about your application, there may be a non-interrupt solution.

Create a subclass of QObject and move it to a unique QThread.

In the object, call startTimer(100).

In timerEvent(), poll the hardware.  Emit a signal as necessary.

In Qt4, signals and slots are automatically queued across threads.

Comment: Thanks ken but this poling is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with hardware then you can use OS specific method to do this. Like epoll, kqueue or similar method.